# Determine who is using ws2_32!WSARecv or ws2_32!recv

Tags: windbg

How do I determine which processes are using WS2_32 to receive data from a socket?

What I'd like is, for example, to simply output a call stack whenever some process calls ws2_32!WSARecv or ws2_32!recv so that I know where the call came from.

I suspect I may need to use WinDbg with kb, but have never done true kernel-level debugging with kb before. I have done a fair amount of process-level debugging with cdb and WinDbg PC-to-PC over a serial connection.

I've been Googling, but so far nothing I've read gives a clear way of doing it. If someone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.  I'm not afraid to spend time reading, I just don't want to waste more time going down rabbit holes.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

***[edit]** Thank you Marc for the hint of using XPerf and also for the link.  This was exactly what I needed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETW using xperf (or WPA on Win8.x) is better suited for this task. The article [‘Hidden’ ETW Stack Trace Feature – Get Stacks All Over the Place!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/06/08/hidden-etw-stack-trace-feature-get-stacks-all-over-the-place.aspx?Redirected=true) does exactly what you want.

In that article they are looking for callers of `ws2_32!socket` so it'll be easy to follow their steps and look for callers of `ws2_32!WSASend` and `ws2_32!send` instead.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a WinDbg solution, but maybe helpful for someone who comes here and wants to do a similar thing without kernel debugging.*

[Rohitab API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) provides API logging capabilities. In the API filter tool window select WS2_32.dll, then check the methods `WSARecv` and `recv`.

Drawbacks of this approach:

- there's no easy way to monitor all processes with a single click
- it doesn't provide an overview of all calls in a single window, just a per process view
- on 64 bit Windows, you will need to run the 64 bit and 32 bit version in parallel to be able to monitor all processes.